# Time in yaml file parsed inconsistently

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am parsing yaml files with `pyyaml` and I noticed inconsistent results. Here is an excerpt of the parsed yaml file:

```
    times:
        # - HH:MM:SS
         - 00:05:00
         - 01:00:00
         - 05:00:00
         - 10:00:00
         - 15:00:00
```

Parsed with `yaml.safe_load('path/to/file.yml')`, this will result in the following `dict`:

```
    {'times': [
            '00:05:00',
            '01:00:00',
            '05:00:00',
            36000,
            54000]
    }
```

Evidently, the items with leading zeros were interpreted as a string, while those without leading zeros were interpreted as a time representation and converted to a timestamp.

Is there a way to have all items interpreted as a timestamp?